# How to put the form view inside an inherited twig view?

Tags: symfony, twig

In the view related to ViciousAmateur:Default:Index Controller/acction I want to add a form to filter paginated results (KnpPaginatorBundle). In my controller I create the form and return the view with the form variable. (Ahh.. If I put the form directly in the view it works as expected).

```
/**
 * @Route("/{page}", defaults={"page" = 1}, name="homepage")
 * @Route("/")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request, $page)
{
    $filters = new Filters();
    $form = $this->createForm(new FiltersType(), $filters);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Do something with form submited data
        }
    }

    // Do something when index action loads, pagination etc...

    return $this->render('ViciousAmateurBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'pagination' => $pagination
        )
    );
}
```

But if I try to put the form into a twig include (to make the view inherited/separate) passing the form variable to that view... then it doesn't works. I get this response **"Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Se ha restablecido la conexión."** (Some words are in Spanish) That's my view:

```
// file: ViciousAmateurBundle:Default:index.html.twig
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ include('ViciousAmateurBundle:Default:filters.html.twig', {'form': form}) }}

    {% block filters %}
    {% endblock %}

    // Stuff in the body
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, the form view is inherited (the extends clause) from index and adds the code to its "filters" twig block...

```
// file: ViciousAmateurBundle:Default:filters.html.twig
{% extends 'ViciousAmateurBundle:default:index.html.twig' %}

{% block filters %}
<section class="filters">
    <form action="{{ path('homepage') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="filters">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.country) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.country, { 'attr': { 'placeholder': 'País', 'class': 'input-block-level' } }) }}

            // Some more form fields...

        {{ form_rest(form) }}

        <input type="submit" class="filters_submit btn btn-large btn-block" />
    </form>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Then... It's possible to do that thing ? To put the form in an inherited view (the filters view from index) passing to it the form variable given by the controller ??? It should work ? What I'm missing or doing wrong ? Thank you

Comment: Here's my dev.log after try to render the page. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RsKsWqnf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done was to remove the extends clause and the twig block to the filters.html.twig view. And just included it in the index.html.twig page within the filters twig block.

index.html.twig

```
...
{% block filters %}
    {{ include('ViciousAmateurBundle:Default:filters.html.twig', {'form': form}) }}
{% endblock %}
...
```

filters.html.twig

```
<section id="filters">
<form action="{{ path('homepage') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="filters">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

        {{ form_errors(form.country) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.country, { 'attr': { 'placeholder': 'País', 'class': 'input-block-level' } }) }}

        {{ form_errors(form.city) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.city, { 'attr': { 'placeholder': 'Ciudad', 'class': 'input-block-level' } }) }}

        {{ form_errors(form.gender) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.gender, { 'attr': { 'placeholder': 'Género', 'class': 'input-block-level' } }) }}

        {{ form_errors(form.sexual_orientation) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.sexual_orientation, { 'attr': { 'placeholder': 'Orientación sexual', 'class': 'input-block-level' } }) }}

    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <input type="submit" id="toggleFilters1" class="filters_submit btn btn-large btn-block" value="Filtrar" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the syntax in Symfony2.1 is:

```
{% include "ViciousAmateurBundle:Default:filters.html.twig" with { form: form} %}
```

[Twig include function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html)

Comment: Ops sorry, not said that I'm using 2.2.* version. The syntax changed. Here's explained at the bottom of the anchor link in a quote: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/templating.html#including-other-templates